# how to check if there is user name in database

Tags: java, mysql, database, jsp

how to find existing user name in database in this code since i am new to this language can u please help me....

```
<%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
<%@page import="pack.Db"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%
    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    String pass = request.getParameter("pass");
    String role = request.getParameter("role");
    String gender = request.getParameter("gender");
    String age = request.getParameter("age");
    String email = request.getParameter("email");
    String date = request.getParameter("date");
    try {
        Connection con = Db.getConnection();
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        int i = st.executeUpdate("insert into data values('" + name + "','" + pass + "','" + role + "','" + gender + "','" + age + "','" + email + "','" + date + "','NO','Waiting')");
        if (i != 0) {
            response.sendRedirect("signup.jsp?Registration Successfully");
        } else {enter code here
            response.sendRedirect("signup.jsp?Registration Failed");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error in signupction" + e.getMessage());
    }
%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here before insert the user you can

1)Check username already exist by fetching name from Database

2)If exist send the error to the UI

3)If does not exist insert the user.

Here is the code snippet:

```
 try {
     Connection con = Db.getConnection();
     Statement st = con.createStatement();

    ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery("select name from data where name='"+name+"'");
    if(result.next())
    {
        response.sendRedirect("signup.jsp?Registration Failed");
    }
    else{
         int i = st.executeUpdate("insert into data values('" + name + "','" + pass + "','" + role + "','" + gender + "','" + age + "','" + email + "','" + date + "','NO','Waiting')");
         if (i != 0) {
                response.sendRedirect("signup.jsp?Registration Successfully");
          } 
          else {
                response.sendRedirect("signup.jsp?Registration Failed");
         }
    }
    } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error in signupction" + e.getMessage());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
try {
    Connection con = Db.getConnection();
    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    String sqlcommand = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE uname = " + name;
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sqlcommand);
    if(rs.next()){
       response.sendRedirect("signup.jsp?Registration Failed");
    }else{
       int i = st.executeUpdate("insert into data values('" + name + "','" + pass + "','" + role + "','" + gender + "','" + age + "','" + email + "','" + date + "','NO','Waiting')");
       if (i != 0) {
         response.sendRedirect("signup.jsp?Registration Successfully");
       }
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Error in signupction" + e.getMessage());
}
```